# How to adjust grid in Django Admin Forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-templates, django-views

I've just created a model in Django and want to use the admin form to enter information for it. The problem I'm having is that my field names are so long that they overlap the edit boxes where their values are to be entered.

If one follows the tutorial in the Django website, it's as if the label "Question:" overlapped the edit box where one was supposed to enter a question.

Any thoughts, comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) django's admin form template for that specific model  and add necessary CSS or JS to it. I think in your case CSS should be enough.

Comment: That is what I can't figure out how to do. I've found the file fieldset.html, that seems to generate the page I'm looking at. I think I need to figure out how to modify a form-row class that is defined in forms.css....

Comment: You can redefine fieldset.html but it will affect all admin pages in your project. I'd recommend overriding only change_form.html specific for necessary model and adding a STYLE tag to reset LABEL width (or set it as "display: block").

Comment: Very old response and the linked-to documentation from v1.4 is dead.  Current version 4.2 link is:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Answer (score 1):

The label has 8em width. The simplest way is to adjust label content by using shorter words and put detail info in help_text at the bottom of the field. Remember you could use hypen sign to break any long word manually.

If you cannot just follow ilvar's suggestion.